# How to retrieve multiple data from table using shell script?

Tags: oracle, shell

```
var=`sqlplus -s user/pass <<EOF
      2 set feedback off
      3 set heading off
      4 set pagesize 2000
      5 select * from orders;
      6 exit
      7 EOF`
      8 cnt=${#var[@]}
      9 for (( i=0 ; i<cnt ; i++ ))
     10 do
     11 echo $var[0]
     12 echo $var[1]
     13 done
```

This is the code I am using but it is always giving me the last row.

Here is the result:

```
$ sh test.sh
[0] 5 555 c52
[1] 5 555 c52
```

Here is the table:

```
ORDER_ID          QUANTITY EAN        C_ID
--------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
o1                      14 551        c1
o2                      14 552        c2
o3                       3 553        c3
o4                       4 554        c4
o5                       5 555        c5
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `var` isn't an array. It's simple scalar variable contains multiline text. Therefore you can't use it for loop to retrive the variable contents. Try something like this:

```
~$ var=$(sqlplus -s user/pass@db_tnsalias <<EOF
   set feedback off
   set heading off
   set pagesize 0
   select * from orders;
   exit
EOF
)
~$ echo "$var" | while read line; do echo $line; done
o1 14 551 c1
o2 4 552 c2
o3 3 553 c3
o4 4 554 c4
o5 5 555 c5
```

Take note:

- double quotes around `$var` to avoid a variable expansion
- `pegesize 0` to remove first empty line

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work because the sql command returns lines which are then fed into an array word by word. So afterwards there is no indication left where a data row ends and the next begins. Instead of filling an array, I'd pipe the whole output into a while loop which reads from stdin like so:

```
{ sqlplus -s system/subho94 <<EOF
set feedback off
set heading off
set pagesize 2000
select * from orders;
exit
EOF
} |
while read orderid quantity ean cid; do
  echo $orderid $quantity $ean $cid
done
```

Note that while reading lines from stdin the shell will tokenize the lines but applying IFS, which results in all white space being stripped from the columns, but I think that is what you want anyways.